# FTP using filezilla

Tags: ftp, port, ftp-client, filezilla

Its been so long since i've needed to ftp something I seem to have forgotten how to do it.

(server address)I have got my ftp address
(password)I have got my password
(port)I have assumed the port is 20 or 21

I am using Filezilla and the above are the only information it requests.
I had connected it to localhost without any problems apart from it not showing the files that are stored in my htdocs folder (I had a look to see if i needed to direct to the folder but couldn't find anything to say that it was necessary) the port number for that was 14147. When I try to connect to a remote host I keep receiving errors saying maybe the port is incorrect or "Connected, waiting for authentication", I cannot leave the port option blank, I have tried 20, 21, 25, 80, 8080, 14147 and a couple of random ones after getting frustrated.
I have gone onto my provider and tried to find the port but cant seem to find the port they use for anything other than the emails, that was 25 and that is when i get the Connected, waiting for authentication message.

In short can someone please direct me to an idiots guide to FTP'ing, I know it should be quite straight-forward, but i'm really struggling. I have looked at a few tutorials but as it is such a straight forward job none seem to address my issue.

Please help (I assume what im trying to ftp doesnt make a difference?)

Comment: because as id tried everything I could think of I was wondering if it could be to do with what I am uploading i.e. php I will assume by your question it most defiantly is not.

Answer (score 1):

Little confusing to understand but if you need help setting up an ftp servers, heres how:

1. download and install Filezilla server(assuming this is done)
2. when it asks for what server leave it at default(host is 127.0.0.1
       and port 14147)
3. set up a group. for this go to edit->groups and
       hit add and name it.
4. now go to shared folders and select the
       folder(s) you want this group to access along with what permissions
       they need. Hit ok.
5. now set up a user in your group. Go to
       edit->users
6. Click add, name the account(this will be your
       username) and set the group
7. ensure the box labeled enable account
       is selected and that you have a password set up.
8. hit ok to save
       changes. Now try to connect through localhost using an FTP client.
       if it works then continue on. If it does not work ensure that a
       firewall is not blocking the server
9. set up port forwarding for
       port 21(every router is different so try googling how to do this).
10. test by using your external ip address. Don't know it? try
         [whatismyip.com](http://whatismyip.com)

That should be all you need to do for your new FTP server